# Convert multipolygon geometry into list

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

How can I please convert a multipolygon geometry into a list?
I tried this:

```
mycoords=geom.exterior.coords
mycoordslist = list(mycoords)
```

But I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'exterior'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to loop over geometries within your MultiPolygon.

```py
mycoordslist = [list(x.exterior.coords) for x in geom.geoms]
```

Note that the result is a list of coords lists.

Comment: I tried this and get this error: AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'geoms'

Comment: @mee Only when `geom.type=='MultiPolygon'`.

Comment: `mycoordslist = [list(x.exterior.coords) for x in geom]` will work as of now. if `geom.type == 'MultiPolygon'`

Comment: @PrakashDahal That will stop working in shapely 2.0. You already get a deprecation warning about that in 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

The error raise simply because you are trying to get coordinates from the wrong attribute, `exterior` is an attribute of `Polygon`, not of `MultyPolygon`.

This could work:

```
mycoordslist = [poly.exterior.coords for poly in list(geom)]
```